# Find a specific object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs

I don't understand because I use the method "find" but I get "undefined"...
My data :

```json
[ 
{ "id": 2, "title": "My project", "nameStructure": "Entreprise", "studies": 
    [ 
    {"id": 3, "name": "My stidue", "status": "in prepa" }, 
    { "id": 4, "name": "My second study ", "status": "In"} 
    ], 
    "typeStructure": "Entreprise" 
}, 
{ "id": 3, "title": "My project 2", "nameStructure": "Entreprise 2", "studies": 
    [ 
    {"id": 4, "name": "My stidue 2", "status": "in prepa" }, 
    { "id": 5, "name": "My second study 2 ", "status": "In"} 
    ], 
    "typeStructure": "Entreprise 2" 
}, 
...
 ]
```

I would like to have only the object with the ID 2 for example.

So I wrote :

```js
const id = 2
myarray.filter(p => p.id === id);
```

But it does not work... I always get "undefined"

Thanks for help

Comment: `p.id` is a number, `"2"` is a string. Either change the type or don't use strict comparison `===` -> `==`. I would go with the first option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID is a number, therefore you need to remove the quotes around 2

```
myarray.filter(p => p.id === 2);
```

and the operator === in Javascript means that 2 should be equal to "2" as in value and type

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality

Comment: Oh ok it was the 2 equal...Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
 const arr = [
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "My project",
      nameStructure: "Entreprise",
      studies: [
        { id: 3, name: "My stidue", status: "in prepa" },
        { id: 4, name: "My second study ", status: "In" }
      ],
      typeStructure: "Entreprise"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "My project 2",
      nameStructure: "Entreprise 2",
      studies: [
        { id: 4, name: "My stidue 2", status: "in prepa" },
        { id: 5, name: "My second study 2 ", status: "In" }
      ],
      typeStructure: "Entreprise 2"
    }
  ];


const newItem = arr.find((item) => item.id === 2);
console.log("newItem>>>>", newItem);
```